# Meteorite from Mars?

Tags: meteorites

What kind(s) of science is used to determine that a meteorite is "from Mars"?  How do we know that the meteorite isn't just another rock from space? How is some sort of accuracy statement developed for such a finding?

Comment: http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl/news/whatsnew/index.cfm?FuseAction=ShowNews&NewsID=1525

Answer (score 7):

One way is to compare the ratios of gases (neon, argon, krypton, xenon, nitrogen and carbon dioxide) trapped in the meteroite to those of the Mars atmosphere.  After Don Bogard and Pratt Johnson (1983) compared gases in a meteorite to those measured by the Viking landers and obtained a nearly perfect match, it was no longer scientifically debated whether the meteorite was from Mars.  Meteorites confirmed in this way should be considered as confirmed with a very high confidence level.

Other meteorites are considered to be from Mars based upon mineral composition, for example by oxygen isotope analysis or by the ratio of iron to manganese.

See the following references for more information:

http://www.psrd.hawaii.edu/July99/PSRD-EETA79001.pdf

http://www.imca.cc/mars/martian-meteorites.htm

Comment: Good answer, thanks for including those references. I am unable to vote up, but will retry later. Because many of the readers on this forum are not chemists, you might also want to include an explanation that the evidence is a combination of major element, trace element, and isotopic evidence.

Comment: I'll dig into those references.   Are you aware of assumptions made about the gas trapping process in rock voids? Seems like there could be many noise factors in that process.

Comment: Hard to imagine a process that would lead to such 'noise.' Note that the first four elements are 'noble gasses' - these they do not chemically react with other elements to form compounds that might alter there abundance in the sample. I think @DavePhD is still correct to say (even 15 years later) that meteorite-geochemists think the Mars hypothesis is highly probable.